# Why can't I see "deleted recent questions" on my profile?

Tags: bug, profile-page, deleted-questions, deleted-posts-pages

I have noticed that on one of the Stack Exchange websites, namely http://quant.stackexchange.com, I cannot list my "deleted recent questions":

[image]

Why?

I do have one question that has been deleted less than 60 days ago by Roomba: https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/30300/2183

[image]

It works fine on other Stack Exchange website:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the link doesn't get displayed if you have zero *undeleted* questions. Which makes sense - displaying that for users who truly haven't ever asked a question on the site would simply be confusing. Would probably have to add extra logic so that the link is based on total number of questions (deleted + undeleted) rather than just the number of undeleted questions.

Comment: @animuson yes, basing the link on total number of questions (deleted + undeleted) would make the most sense. Without Google I'd have lost the question.